# Best way to segment data in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a web site which has a number of distinct parts, there is a public marketing site, a members area and a admin section for staff, all three are part of the same website and currently the analytics are all merged.

What I need to do is segment the data into three distinct sections, so I can see what is really going on.

What is the best way to do this? three separate accounts? or would it be better to use a custom variable and tag the sections accordingly? or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take.

First is to create a profile for each part. You will need to create a profile for each part, then make a filter with each profile to only collect data for that part.

For example if the admin area is at `example.com/admin`:

1. New profile named `Admin Area`
2. In the new profile, create a filter called `Include Admin traffic only`
3. Filter type set as *Custom filter* and *Include*
4. Filter field as *Request URI*
5. Filter pattern as `^\/admin\/*$`

Repeat for each domain. Data will only be collected once the profile is created.

([Google's explanation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts#profiles))

The second option is to create an Advanced Segment for each part in your master profile. This will show you the visitors that visited each part.

1. From the *Reporting* tab click *Advanced Segments*
2. Click *New Custom Report*
3. *Name* as `Admin Area`
4. *Include* - *Page* - *Matching RegExp* - `^\/admin\/*$`

It's probably best to do both, a profile for each part and an Advanced Segment in the master profile.